# Laptop BIOS password is unknown

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

I have a Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile v6535 laptop (a rare 2008 machine) that has a BIOS password which I don't know.

I got this laptop from a dump a year ago and the previous user set a BIOS password (note that the keyboard has a spanish layout).  As I tweak the BIOS sometimes, it is hard for me to use a BIOS password generator to get to the BIOS, because I need to have another PC alongside to do it.

I disassembled the laptop and cleared the CMOS battery, but it still didn't work.

There is a high chance that the setup password is written in a EEPROM chip, But i don't know if it's my case.

Can I read or erase the BIOS setup password somehow?

Comment: I have 4 different password generators for fujitsu, post the code and I can generate a master password. Two ways to get a code, enter any wrong password 3 times in a row, it should output a code. Some bioses require these 3 specific passwords to be entered in row 3hqgo3 , jqw534 , 0qww294e

Comment: That's what i actually do in order to get to the BIOS settings

Comment: Once in the bios clear the passwords, your question lacks specific information.

Comment: I use a bios **password generator** to enter the BIOS after i typed any wrong password 3 times,and so i need another PC to generate the temporary password . My scope is to find out the actual BIOS password (the permanent one). Hope i made it clear.

Comment: The generator creates the master password you need.

Comment: The BIOS does not let me clear the supervisor password (the one used to gain access) simply because i don't know it. Also, i do not want to use a password generator everytime i want to gain access to the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's been like, 6 years?!?, since I posted this question. But here I am, answering my own question half a decade later.

I still have that laptop (albeit, in a rather poor shape, but functional), and it just happened I came across this really cool github repo: [dogbert/bios-pwgen](https://github.com/dogbert/bios-pwgen). The guy reverse engineered the password protection behind lots of machines, including the Phoenix BIOS on mine.

So it was only logical that I pull my old Fujitsu out of storage and give it a try. And it actually worked!