# Hp6450 Bios password for hard drive replacement

Tags: bios, password-management

is there away to get a bios password for my hp 6450  sn cnu1240llb  product #lf445ec, I am try to replace hard drive

Comment: Passwords are not usually recoverable; however, many system boards have a way (usually setting a jumper) to clear a BIOS password (remove it entirely).

Comment: You will, in all likelihood, need to replace the drive.

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Bios-Password-for-HP-6450B/m-p/5029669/highlight/true#M335864

Comment: The first link in that post has moved to https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/hp-probook-elitebook-bios-password-reset-utility.49497/

Comment: Do you own this computer? Did the previous owner set the password or have you simply forgotten it? While it used to be possible to clear BIOS passwords using jumpers, an easily cleared password is no security and so that practice is not really possible on any modern systems. You either know the password, or you don't. However, changing hard drives doesn't always require changing the BIOS settings, though that can depend on what the system config currently is and what you may want it to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop BIOS password is unknown](https://superuser.com/questions/949421/laptop-bios-password-is-unknown)

Comment: @music2myear That question was about an old BIOS machine. The HP in this question is UEFI and no, there's no way, other than replacing the motherboard.

Comment: That was just one of the several questions about this posted on this site over the years. It seemed likely relevant, but another can be chosen easily if it is more applicable.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That was the case for many old BIOS machines but this one is UEFI so, it's no longer possible that way. The links in comments after yours confirm it.

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you for posting the links confirming it isn't possible, even back in 2013 (UEFI era had just began).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Time to close this question I think.